# unexpected oscillations when using pandas plot()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I've taken some data from the web and loading it into a pandas dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
%pylab inline

loc = 'https://blockchain.info/charts/hash-rate?showDataPoints=false&timespan=all&show_header=true&daysAverageString=1&scale=1&format=csv&address='
df = pd.read_csv(loc, parse_dates = True, 
                 index_col = 0, skiprows = 1, 
                 names = ['Date', 'Hash Rate (Gh/s)'])
```

I then try to plot it using the pandas df.plot command

```
df['Hash Rate (Gh/s)'].plot(logy = True)
```

The plot I receive back has unexpected oscillations [image: made with pandas]

but if I plot the same data with matplotlib

```
plt.semilogy(df['Hash Rate (Gh/s)'])
```

[image: made with matplotlib]

There are none of these oscillations.

I have attempted to use the pandas reindex functionality

```
df_idx = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1])
df = df.reindex(df_idx, fill_value=nan)
```

but as of yet have not found any means of getting rid of these spurious oscillations in the plot. How do I either remove these oscillations or re-index in pandas to eliminate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dates aren't being parsed correctly: they have days first.  If you pass `dayfirst=True` to `read_csv`, it should fix the problem.

```
In [6]: df = pd.read_csv("ooo.csv", skiprows=1, names=['Date', 'Hash Rate (Gh/s)'], parse_dates=True, index_col=0, dayfirst=True)

In [7]: df.head(10)
Out[7]: 
                     Hash Rate (Gh/s)
Date                                 
2009-01-04 18:15:05          0.000000
2009-01-05 18:15:05          0.000000
2009-01-06 18:15:05          0.000000
2009-01-07 18:15:05          0.000000
2009-01-08 18:15:05          0.000000
2009-01-09 18:15:05          0.000696
2009-01-10 18:15:05          0.001541
2009-01-11 18:15:05          0.005269
2009-01-12 18:15:05          0.004424
2009-01-13 18:15:05          0.005717

[10 rows x 1 columns]

In [8]: !head ooo.csv
03/01/2009 18:15:05,0.00004971026962962963
04/01/2009 18:15:05,0.0
05/01/2009 18:15:05,0.0
06/01/2009 18:15:05,0.0
07/01/2009 18:15:05,0.0
08/01/2009 18:15:05,0.0
09/01/2009 18:15:05,0.0006959437748148148
10/01/2009 18:15:05,0.0015410183585185184
11/01/2009 18:15:05,0.005269288580740741
12/01/2009 18:15:05,0.004424213997037036

In [9]: df["Hash Rate (Gh/s)"].plot(logy=True)
Out[9]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0xc4ea58c>
```

produces

[image: figure w/o oscillations]

Comment: Thank you. Very simple solution. I wish it had been clear to me from the output that the datetime formatting was just off.